# How do I make <iframes> load only on a button click?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Friends, 
My issue is that my page is really slow to load, because all of the  load simeltaneously. I am pulling an RSS feed that if you click on the "article" button it will pop up a Modal that has the  inside of it. The problem is that all of the s load simeltaneously.

here is the site:
http://daisy.camorada.com/

I have tried inserting a src into the  but that doesn't work because i guess the iframe loads when the page opens.

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' id='miguel'>TEST ME NOW</button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' id='jamison'>jamison</button>
        <div id="yoyoyo">
            </div>
            <iframe id="gogo">
                </iframe>

<script>
        $('#miguel').on('click', function() {
            alert('clicked');           
            $('#gogogo').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');

        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $('#jamison').on('click', function() {
            alert('clicked JAMISON');       
            $("#yoyoyo").html("<h1>HELLO J</h1><br><iframe class='full-iframe' href='http://news.yahoo.com/three-killed-tribal-clash-libya-001717827.html'></iframe>");

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Html:

```
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="http://my.url" src="about:blank">
</iframe>
```

In your jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var iframe = $("#myiFrame");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
});
```

Or if you wanted to load ALL iframes when you click one button... make sure they all have a `data-src="your.url"` attribute, and then loop through like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("iframe").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ahren. I have re-created your code at daisy.camorada.com/test.php , unfortunately it is not acting properly. Ideas?

Comment: @AlexSpencer - The code is perfect - the only thing is, google doesn't allow itself to be embedded in an iframe! Try another site! (for example, yahoo.com)

Comment: @ahren 
how do i work it out if there is more than one iframe but it has to be triggered separately. two different buttons & two different iframes.

Comment: @ahren I mean, instead of using the Jquery code again & again, one single code for trigerring events. thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="myiFrame">Click me!</a>
<iframe name="myiFrame" src="about:blank">
```

No JavaScript required.

Comment: This is clever.

Answer (score 6):

First, you don't have an element `$('#gogogo')`. The frame is `#gogo`.

Second, set it's `src` not `href`

```
$("#myframe").attr('src', 'http://site.com');
```

If you just want to set it to some HTML and not a URL, use this:

```
$("#myframe").contents().find('html').html("hello");
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/uwovax/2)

Comment: sachleen, I tried your method here:  http://daisy.camorada.com/test2.php at no avail. Are you sure that you can dynamically change an iframe's src and it will load the <iframe>. I want the <iframe> to be invisible and then appear with the src on the click of a button.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` You don't have jQuery.

Comment: now that i have jquery (embarrasing moment) let's take a look at http://daisy.camorada.com/test2.php:

before the button is clicked:

     <iframe id="myiFrame" src="">

after the button is clicked the src="http://www.yahoo.com" is the only thing that is changed

Now, here are the two problems:
1) if you notice the <iframe> is present (not hidden) before the button is clicked
2) the <iframe> is not loading the src after the src is dynamically inserted, can you not insert an src into an iframe and have it load that site on the insert? why?

Comment: `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.` A lot of sites prevent you from displaying them in iframes. Yahoo is one of them. That's why I used my personal site in my example. Use another site (like your own) and check :)

Comment: okay, i used my site alexspencer.me and it is now displaying properly, however, how do i make it so the <iframe> does not show as a blank square when the page is loaded? THANKS! appreciate it!!!

Comment: Combination of http://api.jquery.com/show/ & http://api.jquery.com/hide/ or http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciated it. I figured it out, and I did not even need to use jquery show, hide / toggle. Thanks!

Comment: sachleen, many thanks for demo (+1). It helped me understand your code.