# Load Tab Content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Page Load event, all the tab contents are being loaded, instead i would require to load the tab contents on click of tab...Please share ur ideas how to arrive at. This takes much time to load page. I tried some googled jqueries & JScripts, but no luck...

It would be great help if i get some way to load tab contents on tab click event...

Comment: You can load the content of the tab via ajax, listening for a click event on a tab

Comment: [RTFM](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Here is example that you can use
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery and must use `iframe`, I suggest you check this question: [How do I make <iframes> load only on a button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102464/how-do-i-make-iframes-load-only-on-a-button-click)

Basically you only add the iframe's `src` attribute on click event to load the iframe, otherwise it will load on page load.

Example taken from the link above:

HTML

```
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="http://my.url" src="about:blank">
```

jQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var iframe = $("#myiFrame");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
});
```