# Loading iframe in a jQuery popup only on click

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick, popup

I'm using jQuery to create popup overlay windows using iframe. There are so many iframes in my pages which make loading the whole page extremely slow. I'd like to delay loading the src of iframes until a click is done. Here is the code that I’m using:

```
<a class='COD_open' href='#cod'>COD</a>
<div id='COD' class='well'>
   <iframe name='I1' src='Freq/cod.html' width='500' height='500' ></iframe>
</div>
<script> 
   $(document).click(function () {$('#COD').popup({pagecontainer: '.container',transition: 'all 0.3s'});}); 
</script>
```

There is a similar Q&A suggesting to use getElementById [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015809/only-load-div-iframe-onclick/31418438#31418438) but I was not able to implement this technique in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your solution is [here][1]. I hope this solve your problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102464/how-do-i-make-iframes-load-only-on-a-button-click